# MySQL reset column charset to default

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

considering this below table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `modified_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Is it possible to remove the column specific charset, I.E. `first_name`, `last_name` to not have column charset overwrite so that it takes the table level charset setting?

In other words, what's the ALTER TABLE statement to get the table definition to become like this below?

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `modified_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I've tried

`ALTER TABLE user MODIFY first_name varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL`

and

`ALTER TABLE user MODIFY first_name varchar(40)  CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL;`

Neither of that resets/removes the charset set overwrite on the column, instead it adds collation, so that the column looks like this `first_name varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL`

**UPDATE**

By the way, since this table has the default charset and default collation defined, I would think that the `varchar` columns should have inherit the table default collation, but they are **NOT**! Once the charset is overwritten on the column level, MySQL erroneously pick the overwritten charset's default collation instead, in my case, `utf8mb4_general_ci` is the default collation for `utf8mb4` charset!! See column explanation below

```
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM user;
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field           | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| modified_at     | datetime     | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| created_at      | datetime     | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| id              | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| first_name      | varchar(40)  | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| middle_name     | varchar(40)  | utf8mb4_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| last_name       | varchar(40)  | utf8mb4_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| username        | varchar(100) | utf8mb4_general_ci | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| active          | tinyint(1)   | NULL               | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets#The_basic_ALTER_TABLE_command_with_a_specified_charset) suggests a 2 pass conversion from one character set to another - maybe that would work

Comment: @PaulF I think that would work! Going to to try it later.

Comment: Nah, I spoke too soon. It didn't work :( While investigating the issue, it did give me a lead which solves my original issue myself!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out myself after getting some leads from the link of WordPress's charset migration guide that @PaulF pointed out.

The answer is no, there is no default to reset the column to. Once the table has a specific charset/collation set other than the default of database, the collation setting stays with the column. I.E.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_default` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
--
mysql> show create table test_default\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test_default
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test_default` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In other words, `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` will stay with the column `foo` as it's not a default collation for `utf8mb4` charset.

Also, if one wants to set collation to any other than `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, `COLLATE new_collation_here` for the column will still shows up in CREATE TABLE statement.